# Count the number of matching elements in two arrays in Java and how to generate more than 100

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

How to find a way to make my code count the number of matching elements in two arrays of the same size (same value, same position). For instance, if array1 has 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, and array2 has 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, there is one matching element, the 3. How can I get my code to perform this seemingly simple task? And it would tell me how many by saying I have 1 that match 3 that match or any other numbers? Like i want it to count how many that matched and give me a number.

Those are my two arrays that generate 100 numbers. I also want them to generate 10,000,000 numbers and im not sure how to do that? They are generating 100 but i want it to be 10,000,000 how?

And for this code:

```
        if (store[t] ==store[w])
        {
            maching = maching +1;
            System.out.println("Generated: " + maching);
        }

    }
   //return maching;
}
```

It should count the matching ones and give me the amount that matches. But what it is doing is that it gives me: like if three matched it gives me this: Generated: 1, Generated 1, Generated 1, instead of just giving me a 3. Also i commented the return matching out because it is giving me errors so i comment it out. Maybe if i get return matching to work would it solve the whole thing? Im not sure what is causing the problem? Thank you.

I want it to count how many numbers that matched between the two arrays. So when i get 6 numbers matched between those two arrays it should say that i got 6 that matched.

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

for (int t = 0; t < 100; ++t)
{
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
    store[t] = randomNumber;
}

int matching =0;
for ( int w = 0; w< 100; ++w)
{
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
    count[w] = randomNumber;
    int t =0;

    if (store[t] ==count[w])
    {
        matching = matching +1;
        System.out.println("Generated: " + maching);
    } 
}


System.out.println("Done.");
}
```

Comment: You're resetting `maching` (which, BTW, lacks a "t") every time. Declare it outside the for-loop, not inside.

Comment: Your question asks to compare elements in two arrays. But you only have one array: store. Start by fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int w = 0; w< 100; ++w)
{
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
    int t =0;
    int maching =0;
    if (store[t] ==store[w])
    {
        maching = maching +1;
        System.out.println("Generated: " + maching);
    } 
}
```

- here you have only one array, `store[]` and the elements were assigned in your (another) for loop (with `t`)
- in the above codes, you set `t=0`, and compare `store[t] and store[w]`, so what you did was: compare `store[0] with store[0],store[1]..store[99]` I don't think it is what you want.
- if you don't want to assign the 2nd array, I think you should at least compare  `store[w] with randomNumber instead of store[t]`

Comment: I added another array and it is doing the same thing as before?

Comment: Also i put randomNumber instead of store[t] and still doing the same thing? which is like this

Comment: @user2989685 you should not use `store[t]` in that loop, use `store[w]` please.

Comment: Generates 10 million numbers
Generated: 1
Generated: 1
Done.

Comment: OK store[w] what about count[]?

Comment: @user2989685 you know how to access array in java, don't u?  try `if (store[w] ==count[w])`

Comment: @user2989685 also, you reset the `matching` to `0` in your for loop. you should put the `matching=0` out of the for loop.

Comment: Sorry yes i had it like this: if (store[w] ==count[w]) and yes the problem was matching=0 i put it outside. But now it is giving me instead of the 1 1 1 now it is 1 2 3?

Comment: if you want to constantly print `1`, what was the `matching` var for? just remove that variable, and `System.out.println("Generated: 1");` @user2989685 btw, you have known the problems in your codes, do some research. and don't update the question constantly with your new changes. SO is not your version control repo. Good luck

Comment: No sorry this is not what i meant. i meant that i want one answer not three answers like: 111 or 123, i want it to be: 3 or 5 or 2 or etc. Also i was updating because i thought that others might benefit from it. Im sorry. Also "SO is not your version control repo." not sure what you meant?